# how to get the latest price in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I need get the price of lasted QuoteDate.

Right now i have query like these

```
SELECT      dbo.INMT.Material, dbo.INMT.LastVendor, dbo.INMT.AvgCost, dbo.MSQD.Status, dbo.MSQH.QuoteDate, dbo.MSQD.UnitPrice
FROM         dbo.INMT INNER JOIN
                      dbo.MSQD ON dbo.INMT.MatlGroup = dbo.MSQD.MatlGroup AND dbo.INMT.Material = dbo.MSQD.Material INNER JOIN
                      dbo.MSQH ON dbo.MSQD.MSCo = dbo.MSQH.MSCo AND dbo.MSQD.Quote = dbo.MSQH.Quote
GROUP BY dbo.INMT.Material, dbo.INMT.LastVendor, dbo.INMT.AvgCost, dbo.MSQD.Status, dbo.MSQD.UnitPrice, dbo.MSQH.QuoteDate
ORDER BY dbo.INMT.Material
```

and get the following result

[image]

and how can i run a query just get the highlighted record.i try to do something like where QuoteDate =max......but maybe my grouyping is not correct.

thanks

Comment: just simplely ignore the TOP(100) PERCENT. Sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, assuming SQL Server 2005+, you can use a  `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  I.Material, 
            I.LastVendor, 
            I.AvgCost, 
            MD.Status, 
            MH.QuoteDate, 
            MD.UnitPrice,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY I.Material, I.LastVendor, 
                                                 I.AvgCost, MD.Status, 
                                                 MD.UnitPrice
                                    ORDER BY MH.QuoteDate DESC)
    FROM dbo.INMT I
    INNER JOIN dbo.MSQD MD
        ON I.MatlGroup = MD.MatlGroup 
        AND I.Material = MD.Material 
    INNER JOIN dbo.MSQH MH
        ON MD.MSCo = MH.MSCo 
        AND MD.Quote = MH.Quote
)
SELECT  Material, 
        LastVendor, 
        AvgCost, 
        Status, 
        QuoteDate, 
        UnitPrice
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Sorry i use sql sever managerment studio. It does work with CTE

Comment: @user1723572 I'm not sure if you are asking me something with that comment, or just letting me know that this in facts works for you

Comment: Sorry, my misunderstanding. I just create a simple LasteDate View and join with other table. just lazy to write a subquery. Thank you for you help.

Comment: to get something like this working I had to remove the table aliases from the final select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use HAVING QuoteDate=max... after the order by clause.